# Python range function for Double values in Java 8 using streams

Tags: java, java-8

I wanted to created a array of doubles in Java containing values ranging from 0 to 100 with a step of 0.1

In Python one would use the range function: `range(0, 100, 0.1)`

In Java 8, this would work:

```
Double[] x = DoubleStream.iterate(0.1, i -> i + 0.1).limit(1000).boxed().toArray(Double[]::new);
```

Is there anything simpler that I could use?

Comment: Since a "range" operation can never generate null values, why use a memory-wasting `Double[]` and not a `double[]`?

Comment: @Andreas that will also definitely help remove one more method operation from the stream pipeline making it shorter (which I assume is what OP means by "anything simpler").

Comment: @Aomine Yeah, changing `.boxed().toArray(Double[]::new)` to `.toArray()` is certainly much simpler.

Comment: What version of python allows you to create a range with floating step? Mine certainly does not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution appears to work, but it suffers from floating-point round-off with successive calculations.

> [0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7999999999999999, 0.8999999999999999, 0.9999999999999999, 1.0999999999999999,

It appears that `DoubleStream` doesn't have a `range` method, but [`IntStream` does, `rangeClosed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#rangeClosed(int,int)), but you don't control the increment.  (There exists `range` too, but the ending parameter is not included in the range.)

> Returns a sequential ordered `IntStream` from `startInclusive` (inclusive) to `endInclusive` (inclusive) by an incremental step of 1.

You can get around the cumulative floating-point round-off errors by streaming some `int`s then dividing by `10.0` to get your increments of `0.1`.  Also, as has been commented, it is simpler to have a primitive array `double[]` to avoid boxing and extra memory usage.

```
double[] y = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 1000)
    .mapToDouble(i -> i / 10.0)
    .toArray();
```

> [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5,

Of course there is always the basic `for` loop, which looks quite simple to me.

```
double[] z = new double[1001];
for (int i = 0; i < z.length; i++) { z[i] = i / 10.0; }
```

Comment: To make it even simpler: `double[] y = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 1000).mapToDouble(i -> i / 10d).toArray();` --- Unless OP specifically needs a `Double[]`, it's also a waste of memory compared to using a `double[]`.

Comment: @Andreas You're right; I've added that to my answer.

Comment: Pythons `range()` is upper-exclusive, same as Javas `range()`, so don't use `rangeClosed()`.

Comment: @Andreas Then the Python code wasn't quite correct, because the OP was trying to create a range of "0 to 100", which I read as "0 through 100", as opposed to "0 up to, but not including, 100".

Answer (score 0):

When you say "Is there anything simpler that I could use?" I'd assume "simpler" in this case means "shorter" code.

Using the stream API there's nothing in place to make your current code "shorter". probably explains why Java is not one of the top code golfing languages eh.. but it gets the job done.

I might be stating the obvious but one thing you could always do though is refactor/hide your current logic into a helper method `range(p1, p2, p3)` then you'll never have to see it again if you don't want to and can just invoke `range(...)`.

On another note, good shout made by [@rgettman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53566943/python-range-function-for-double-values-in-java-8-using-streams/53567052#53567052) in terms of the "floating-point round-off" so take that into consideration.